# Get last data recorded of the date and group it by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

`tbl_totalMonth` has `id`,`time`, `date` and `kwh` column.

I want to get the last recorded data of the months and group it per month so the result would be the name of the month and kwh.

the result should be something like this:

```
month    | kwh
------------
January  | 150
February | 400
```

the query I tried: (but it returns the max kwh not the last kwh recorded)

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, a.date) as monthly, max(a.kwh) as kwh
                        from tbl_totalMonth a
                        WHERE date > = DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0, GETDATE() -1 ),0)
                        group by DATENAME(MONTH, a.date)
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data, query you tried and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: tuff without any sample data ..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need something quite different:

```
select *
from (
      select *
          , row_number() over(partition by month(a.date), year(a.date) order by a.date DESC) as rn
      from tbl_totalMonth a
      WHERE date > = DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0, GETDATE() -1 ),0)
     ) d
where rn = 1
```

To get "*the last kwh recorded (per month)*" you need to use row_number() which - per month - will order the rows (descending) and give each one a row number. When that number is 1 you have "the most recent" row for that month, and you won't need `group by` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use group by and month

```
select datename(month, date), sum(kwh)
from tbl_totalMonth 
where date =  (select max(date) from tbl_totalMonth )
group by datename(month, date)
```

if you need only the last row for each month then  youn should use

```
select datename(month, date), khw
from tbl_totalMonth a
inner join (
select max(date) as max_date  
from tbl_totalMonth 
group by month(date)) t on t.max_date = a.date
```

Comment: there is an error "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

Comment: You sample is not clear so  ..  is difficult to understand  .. anyway answer  updated